# What does it mean ** in Django update query?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Currently I am working on old project developed in python 2.7 & django 1.9.13 & during development I have found below kind of code.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
model_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_name, model=model_name)
model_type.model_class().objects.filter(id=10).update(**{'emp_comment': 'hello'})
```

I have read about `ContentType` & know how it works but still not have much clear ideas but what I am not able to figure out is `**{'emp_comment': 'hello'}`.

I have search online for such kind of syntax but not able to find so anyone have idea how above code works ?

Comment: dictionary unpacking

Comment: `f(**{'a': 4})` is equivalent to `f(a=4)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , so what is benefit using ** because using ` 'emp_comment'='hello' ` looks much easier !

Comment: @Moon: here, nothing. Usually it is done when you do not know in advance the names of the parameters. So you create a dictionary, pass some key-value pairs, and then call it with double asterisk.